# Override append method (<<) of an ActiveRecord property

Tags: ruby, activerecord, module, overriding

I have an ActiveRecord class who's property is an array (Postgres array column) and I want the items in the array to be unique. What's the best way to override methods that take place on the array itself such as #<< ?

```
module PgTags

  def tags=(value)
    write_attribute :tags, value.uniq
  end

end

class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgTags
end

r = Rule.new
r.tags = %w(one two one)
puts r.tags # outputs ['one', 'two']
r.tags << 'one'
puts r.tags # should still output ['one', 'two']
```

Comment: What version of ActiveRecord are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `r.tags << value` you can also see it like this `r.tags.<<(value)`. The `tags` method will return an instance of `Array` and then this will happen: `array.<<(value)` the array will receive the `<<` method, not the `tags` attribute.

*You'd have to overwrite the `<<` method on `Array`*.

It'd be best to take a step back up to the `r` object and add an `add_tags` method to `Rule` to implement your proposed logic. What you're asking for is possible but more complicated to implement than this:

```
module PgTags
  def tags=(value)
    write_attribute :tags, value.uniq
  end

  def add_tags(*t)
    self.tags = (tags << t).flatten.uniq 
  end
end

class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgTags
end

r = Rule.new
r.tags = %w(one two one)
puts r.tags #=> ['one', 'two']
r.tags.add_tags 'one'
r.tags.add_tags 'three'
puts r.tags #=> ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

The `add_tags` method behaves like you'd expect when you used `<<` except that it handles the uniq logic and assigning the new value to the rule's own `tags` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach (now that I see this is Postgres) would this:

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :ensure_tags_unique

  private
  def ensure_tags_unique
    self.tags = self.tags.uniq
  end
end
```

This keeps the `<<` and `=` functionality built into AR.

Comment: No, PostgreSQL supports standard SQL array columns and so does AR, there is no `serialize` kludge involved.

Comment: @muistooshort I missed the part of the question mentioning a Postgres array column. And now I learned something new about ActiveRecord - thanks!